# How to read the xml file being used by another process in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on asp.net application.
In my application I'm tryin to read one xml file which is used by some ohter c++ process.
But I'm getting the error like file is being used by another process.

I tried as follows.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("./" + webPageXml),FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read,FileShare.ReadWrite);

                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("./" + webPageXml));
```

Here streamreader is thowing the error at the time of intialization.
pls help me asap

Answer (score 0):

You will have to modify the other process's code to open the file in shared mode.  There is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

You Must close that file before use it. Other wise share that file and use file.
May be this help to you..